# How do I show a hidden optgroup using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display an outgroup based on the choice the user makes on another dropdown. The first dropdown contains a list of islands. When the user selects an island, the second dropdown will display the villages located on their chosen island. I've made the optgroups hidden, and my plan was to display/show the optgroups based on the user input. I'm quite new to Javascript so I apologize if my code is wrong:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var island = document.getElementById("Island");
  var village = document.getElementById("Village");
  if (island.value==='Saipan'){
    document.getElementById("SaipanVillage").style.visibility = "visible";
  }else if(island.value==='Tinian'){
    document.getElementById("TinianVillage").style.visibility = "visible";
  }else if(x.value==='Rota'){
    document.getElementById("RotaVillage").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row mt-n3">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                        <label>Island</label>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" id="Island" name="Island" onchange="myFunction()">
                            <option></option>
                            <option>Saipan</option>
                            <option>Tinian</option>
                            <option>Rota</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                        <label>Village</label>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" id="Village" name="Village">
                            <option></option>
                            <optgroup label="======ROTA======" id="RotaVillage" value="RotaVillage" hidden>
                                <option>Afatung Village</option>
                                <option>Agatasi (Payapai) Village</option>
                                <option>Agusan Village</option>
                            </optgroup>
                            <optgroup label="======SAIPAN======" id="SaipanVillage" value="SaipanVillage" hidden>
                                <option>Achugao Village</option>
                                <option>Tapochao Village</option>         
                                <option>Tottotville Village</option>
                            </optgroup>
                            <optgroup label="======TINIAN======" id="TinianVillage" value="TinianVillage" hidden>
                                <option>Aguijan Village</option>
                                <option>Carolinas Village</option>
                                <option>Carolinas Heights Village</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: `x.value` x is undefined in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the boolean hidden property of DOM elements to show and hide them. hidden is not the same as visible (oddly enough).

Try:

```
document.getElementById("SaipanVillage").hidden = false;
```

Comment: I'd recommend testing this on iOS devices. In that past, I've tried a similar approach (setting `display: none;` for `<option>` elements instead of using the `hidden` attribute for an `<optgroup>`) and we found that the options still appears in the list on iOS devices. It looked like it was necessary to remove them from the DOM entirely to make them disappear from all browsers and devices.